# access node.js hashmap after it's finished populating // AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, promise

So I'm working on a lambda in AWS, and node.js is also new to me. I'm fairly sure this has to do with nodejs being asynchronous and would be solved with promise / async / await but no solution is helping me out. I've tried numerous examples but I'm unable to tailor it to what I have. I've super simplified my code to the below:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var es = require('event-stream');
let m = new Map();
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
let params = {...}; //details omitted, but refers to a csv file
let s3 = new aws.S3();

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(es.split()).on('data'), (row) => {
       let dat = row.toString().split(',').map(function(x) {return x.trim() });
       m.set(dat[0], dat[1]); // there's actually around 100 lines of logic that I'm simplifying
   });
console.log(m.size);
```

I understand why I'll always get size 0, but I can't find the workaround. The goal here after the map has finished populating is to iterate through it and push all the elements into dynamoDB. (I don't do it directly because there are a lot of updates and would require lots of docClient.get / .query / .put) I just need the map to be done populating (in other words, the stream has finished). I'm slightly worried that I've simplified it too much and part of the answer will involve making additional promises to the logic I've omitted, but I'll start here, since testing this code also yields size 0.

And help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is asynchronicity. The structure of your code, simplified:

```
// 1
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(es.split()).on('data'), (row) => {
  ...
  // 3
});
// 2
console.log(m.size);
```

Execution follows 1-2-3, so the console.log happens before any data has arrived. You can listen for the close event and print the result there:

```
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(es.split()).on('data'), (row) => {
  ...
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log(m.size);
}
```